# Omit ‘which are’ or not?

Tags: grammar

1. Why do the apps on App Store take bigger space than those on Google Play Store?
2. Why do the apps on App Store take bigger space than those ‘which are’ on Google Play Store?

Is the first sentence clear enough and grammatically correct or should I say/write the second one?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is clear enough except for the use of 'bigger'.  Common use would be "more'

The addition of 'which are' in the second sentence is also correct, but lacks the directness of the first.

I would use the following:

"Why do the apps on App Store take more space than those on Google Play Store?"